# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4 when i try to retrieve all list items from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've been working on a project in part of it I needed to bring a list of data and do some filtering on it, some of those filters are just working fine but I've been facing that problem where the part of getting all the data when I press the button **all** retrieve all the items of the list and show them into listview.builder() with different Card shapes based on grouping similar data **i.e** a card designed for data.type[tests] & another card designed for data.type[offers] ..etc.
So when I press **all** button it shows only the first 4 items inside the listview + it doesn't show data in the card design that supposed to have base on it's group filtering.

**here I'm getting the data from firestore**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Test{

  final String details;
  final String name;
  final String price;
  final String type;

  Test({
    this.details,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.type,
  });

  factory Test.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return Test(
      details: doc.data()['details'],
      name: doc.data()['name'],
      price: doc.data()['price'],
      type: doc.data()['type'],

    );
  }
}
```

..........................

```
import 'package:ilab/services/User.dart';

class Services {
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tests');

  // test list from snapshot
  List<Test> _testsListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Test(
          details: doc.data()['details'] ?? '',
          name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
          price: doc.data()['price'] ?? '',
          type: doc.data()['type'] ?? '');
    }).toList();
  }

// Get tests stream
  Stream<List<Test>> get Tests {
    return _db.snapshots().map(_testsListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

**my component starts here**

```
List<String> alphabets = [
  'all',
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
... etc
]

List<Test> filteredTests = List();
  List<Test> tests = List(); 
  Color color = KWhiteColor;
  int Index;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      filteredTests = tests;
  }
```

**here is the code of giving a card desgin based on the type of data**

```
 // return different cardshape for different group of data 
  Widget _card(int index) {
    if (filteredTests
        .where((user) => user.type.toLowerCase().contains('باقة'))
        .toList()
        .isNotEmpty) {
      return PackageCardDesign(
        packageName: filteredTests[index].name,
        price: '${filteredTests[index].price} YR',
        details: filteredTests[index].details.toLowerCase(),
        colour: Packgecolors[index],
        icon: Icons.ac_unit_outlined,
        type: filteredTests[index].type,
      );
    } else if (filteredTests
        .where((user) => user.type.toLowerCase().contains('تحليل'))
        .toList()
        .isNotEmpty) {
      return TestCardDesign(
        colour: TestOffercolors[index],
        testName: filteredTests[index].name,
        details: filteredTests[index].details.toLowerCase(),
        price: '${filteredTests[index].price} YR',
        type: filteredTests[index].type,
      );
    } else if (filteredTests
        .where((user) => user.type.toLowerCase().contains('عرض'))
        .toList()
        .isNotEmpty) {
      return OfferCardDesign(
        colour: TestOffercolors[index],
        testName: filteredTests[index].name,
        // details: filteredUsers[index].details.toLowerCase(),
        price: '${filteredTests[index].price} %',
        // type: filteredUsers[index].type,
      );
    }
  }
```

**here is the code of creating and printing the top three buttons**

```
  ReusableTestChip mainThreeButtonChip(
      {@required String text, String buttonName, Function onTap}) {
    return ReusableTestChip(
      ontap: onTap,
      cardChild: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: selectedButton == buttonName ? KWhiteColor : KInActiveColor,
          fontSize: 18.0, //25.0,
          fontFamily: 'Cairo-Italic',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      colour: selectedButton == buttonName ? KInActiveColor : KWhiteColor,
    );
  }


  // print Main Three Top Button method using for loop to iterate through loop of strings
  List<ReusableTestChip> printMainThreeButtonMethod() {
    List<ReusableTestChip> allButtons = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      String button = buttons[i];

      var newItem = mainThreeButtonChip(
        text: button,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedButton = buttons[i];
            if (buttons[i] == 'تحاليل') {
              // setState(() {
              //   _card = offerList();
              // });

              filteredTests = tests
                  .where((u) => (u.type.toLowerCase().contains('تحليل')))
                  .toList();
            } else if (buttons[i] == 'عروض') {
              filteredTests = tests
                  .where((u) => (u.type.toLowerCase().contains('عرض')))
                  .toList();
            } else if (buttons[i] == 'باقات') {
              filteredTests = tests
                  .where((u) => (u.type.toLowerCase().contains('باقة')))
                  .toList();
            }
          });
        },
        buttonName: buttons[i],
      );
      allButtons.add(newItem);
    }
    return allButtons;
  }
```

**here is the code of creating and printing the *all* button**

```
  ReusableAlphabetChip alphabetChip(
      {@required String text, String char, Function onTap}) {
    return ReusableAlphabetChip(
      ontap: onTap,
      cardChild: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: selectedAlphabet == char ? KInActiveColor : KSecondaryColor,
          fontSize: 18.0, //25.0,
          fontFamily: 'Cairo-Italic',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      colour: selectedAlphabet == char ? KWhiteColor : KInActiveColor,
    );
  }

// print all button

  List<ReusableAlphabetChip> printAlphabetMethod() {
    List<ReusableAlphabetChip> chars = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
      String char = alphabets[i];

      var newItem = alphabetChip(
        text: char,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedAlphabet = alphabets[i];

            if (alphabets[i] == 'الكل') {
              filteredTests = tests;
              // _foundUsers = _allUsers;
            } else {
              filteredTests = tests
                  .where((u) => (u.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(alphabets[i])))
                  .toList(); //json filter first filter && firebase second filter
              //   _foundUsers = _allUsers.where((u) => (u["name"].toLowerCase().startsWith(alphabets[i]))).toList();
            }
          });
        },
        char: alphabets[i],
      );
      chars.add(newItem);
    }
    return chars;
  }
```

---

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    tests = Provider.of<List<Test>>(context);
    ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(
      initialScrollOffset: 10, // or whatever offset you wish
      keepScrollOffset: true,
    );
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 100,
          title: Image.asset('images/logo.jpeg',
              height: 100.0, alignment: Alignment.center),
        ),
        drawer: AppDrawer(),
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            // applogo(),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                 Row(
                     // top filters
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: printMainThreeButtonMethod(),
                     ),
                 Container(
                  // get all list items
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: printAlphabetMethod()),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 390,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          controller: scrollController,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            Index = index;
                            if (index < filteredTests.length) {
                            return Card(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child:_card(Index)
                              ),
                            );
                            } else {
                              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            }
                          },
                          // itemCount: filteredUsers.length + 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I hope I explained what I'm facing clearly, any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, can you check if this answer helps you?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190510/15774177

Comment: @ZeenathSN hey, I'm still getting the same error even after using that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was in color's list. where I made a list of colors to allow  ListView.builder prints Cards of data that will retrieve with different colors, it turns out that due to color's list is finite and when the ListView.builder reaches the end of it, it returns that error [RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4], So I've made a change on my color's list so when it reaches the end of the list it start over from the beginning and printing new data using the specified colors, like this

```
Color selectedColour(index) {
    Color c;
    if (index % 4 == 0) c = Colors.cyan;
    if (index % 4 == 1) c = Colors.blueGrey;
    if (index % 4 == 2) c = Colors.blue;
    if (index % 4 == 3) c = Color(0xFFea9999);
    return c;
}
```

this is my previous color's list before changing it

```
var Paccolors = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.cyan,
    Colors.blueGrey,
    Colors.pink,
    Colors.black45,
    Colors.lightGreen,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.red
];
```